# Earliest job first algorithm in algorithm design manual by Steven Skiena

Tags: algorithm

While selecting the earliest job we took into consideration that it should not overlap the interval of any previously accepted jobs. (page no.10)

Then in the below quote from the book it is mentioned that, if we take the job in the above mentioned manner, then it will block other movies.

How is it possible when in the algorithm itself we have mentioned that the earliest job will be selected keeping in mind that it does *not* overlap with any other?

Then why the war-peace movie is overlapping with other small movies?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
My doubt comes here that how is it possible when in the algorithm itself we have mentioned that the earliest jon will be selected keeping in mind that it does not internal with any other
```

While selecting the next job, we keep in mind that the next job should be the one:

1. Which comes the earliest
2. And it should not overlap with the previous *accepted* job

In the first example, we first selected the War and Peace job and it is overlapping with other three jobs, but that is not a problem for us as those three are not the accepted jobs. Once our `War and Peace` job ends, we will look for the next job which satisfied the above-mentioned criteria.

Comment: Thanks finally understood